# CSS on Sublime 2 Indents Falsely

Tags: css, sublimetext2, indentation

When using CSS after some time when I go ahead and press enter the text before the '{' moves across, a new soace between '{' and '}' is created but my mouse doesn't move to it. I have to press enter again for this to happen which then creates another new line between the curly brackets.

I want this:

```
.logo {
    position: fixed;
}
```

But instead this happens upon clicking enter after typing the curly brackets:

```
    .logo {
        position: fixed;

}
```

I've tried just restructing the text manually but the same thing repeats with my next code block. I have emmet already and that hasn't really solved my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to Sublime Text 4. The last version of ST2 was released *over 10 years ago*. ST4 is under active development/maintenance.